# Login to desktop environment only for some users

Tags: gnome, permissions, kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

I have a system with Kubuntu on it and two different desktop environments.

Is it possible to restrict the login for one of the two environments for a special user group? Like users of the group parents can login in KDE and Gnome but the users of the group kids can only login into KDE?

Comment: I think you can create different user group with different permissions but cannot restrict user of particular type to a desktop environment.